# Cooker Hood with Off-set flue required

Tags: kitchens

I need a cooker hood with an offset flue.

There is a rafter right where I need to go through.

Whilst searching I came across one that had quite a wide flue that may just work (better measurements needed).

Does anyone know of a hood with an offset flue or anything similar ?

cheers folks

TheOldMan

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

The flue is just a duct, either plastic or metal, so you could create your own offset using standard fittings for the given diameter. If it's a plastic flue you can box it in. If you want an exposed metal flue you could ask someone to weld one.

You can also get flexible concertina-type flues, both metal and plastic. Not as nice to look at nor as efficient as a smooth flue but they might work for you.